# C# WebBrowser stuck on navigating when used in for loop

Tags: c#, logic, webbrowser-control

I have a for loop that changes the URL

```
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i += 50)
            {
                completed = false;
                string currkey = country;
                crawler.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.example.net/func.php?dom=" + currkey + "&key=&start=" + i));
                Console.WriteLine("Navigating to " + "http://www.example.net/func.php?dom=" + currkey + "&key=&start=" + i);
                while (!completed)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
```

This is my documentcompleted handler

```
        crawler.Refresh();
        Console.WriteLine("Getting universities");
        getUniversities();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished getting universities");
        completed = true;
```

When i get rid of the for loop and use a single link, it seems to navigate to the website correctly, but when i use for loop to load websites in order, it seems that the web browser gets stuck in the second iteration.

Example:
currkey = United States

In the first iteration, the website link will be http://www.example.net/func.php?dom="United States"&key=&start=1, and on the next one it will be http://www.example.net/func.php?dom="United States"&key=&start=51. The navigation gets stuck when trying to load the second link.

I have used the boolean completed to note that the current iteration is finished, but it is still stuck.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your document completed. Does it get hit for any iterations beyond the first?

Comment: yes it does, for some reason it won't complete loading, so the line while(!complete) keeps running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Thread.Sleep` call is blocking the `WebBrowser` from continuing to load. What you should be doing is attaching to the `DocumentCompleted` event, and then loading the next page. Please don't use this while/sleep combination in WinForms - you should use the events that the controls expose.

Attach the event:

```
crawler.DownloadCompleted += CrawlerDocumentCompleted;
```

Event handler:

```
private void CrawlerDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //The document has loaded - now do something
}
```

**A final thought**

As it looks like you are implementing a crawler, why are you using the `WebBrowser` control in WinForms to navigate. Surely all you are interested in is the html that the server serves up? Or is the page using JavaScript to load additional elements into the DOM, requiring you to use the `WebBrowser`?

You could use the `WebClient` class and the `DownloadString` or `DownloadStringAsync` methods. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't clear enough. The program is a console program not winform. I did this line -> crawler.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted; in my main.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to just download the HTML and crawl it (assuming no JS on the page) - you should use the WebClient class.

Comment: The problem with WebClient class it that i am currently using document.getelementbyid from the html on that web browser, if i use WebClient i will need to create a html from the string to take the elements i want. Correct me if i am wrong. Also thank you for your answer.

Comment: A tried and tested method is to use the HTML agility pack. There is a great tutorial at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net